# At the end of Avengers: Infinity War, what is the live/dead ratio?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

We all know that Thanos wants to wipe out half of the universe's lives.

> At the end of Infinity War: He snaps his fingers and succeeds in
>  wiping half of the universe. 
>
>  How consistent is Marvel with that information? Do only 50% of the
>  main cast gets wiped out?

Comment: 50% doesn't necessary mean exactly half of any given group. The main cast consists of a variety of different species, and Thanos' quote could be taken as half of each species, or half of all life in general. Also, who do you define as the "main cast"?

Comment: @Mwr247 For any sufficient large group, yes it does.

Comment: @Mwr247 "An ensemble cast is made up of cast members in which the principal actors and performers are assigned roughly equal amounts of importance and screen time in a dramatic production." [check here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_cast)

Comment: There are perfectly good ways of being consistent with that information without wiping out 50% of the main cast members. And, since Marvel Studios probably wants to continue making movies that sell, I'm guessing they're going with one of those ways.

Comment: There will still be deviance though. The NFC won 14 super bowl coin flips in a row, a 0.006% chance. My point is that while every given subset of people should have a 50% chance on average, in practice it won't be so. More than 50% of those in the group on Titan disappeared for example.

Comment: @MishaR I'm not saying that they *absolutely have to* wipe out 50% of the cast (and I feel that they wiped way more than that), my question is about the ratio. I will edit it if that's not obvious.

Comment: @Mwr247 Sure, that's exactly what I want to know!

Comment: Fair enough =) Regarding "main cast" though, this is a movie with tons of actors with extremely varying amounts of screen time that doesn't necessarily reflect importance. Do we count Loki? Shuri? Thanos? Eitri? Okoye? Wong? Pepper? Fury/Maria? Different people might define "main cast" differently, and end up with different ratios. If trying to come up with a specific ratio, some in-universe gauge for who to include would be helpful ("people who have called themselves avengers", or "all named heroes who were seen fighting", etc).

Comment: The better question is how did Thanos handle the planets he had previously purged. For example, did he kill another half of Gamora's home planet? He had already killed half of her people. Did he take half of the remaining half again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Huge spoilers, obviously

By my calculations, 58% (10 out of 17) of the main cast died directly from the purge. So, it's pretty close to 50%. But there are a few caveats to that.

First, who do you consider the "main cast." I'm only including the super heroes here, so, for example, I'm not counting Okoye or Shuri. There's also two of the main cast we don't know about yet: Ant-Man and Hawkeye, so that could skew the results.

Alive

- Iron Man
- War Machine
- Captain America
- Black Widow
- Rocket
- Hulk
- Thor

Dead

- Bucky Barnes
- Black Panther
- Groot
- Scarlet Witch
- Falcon
- Mantis
- Drax
- Star Lord
- Dr. Strange
- Spider-Man

Not Counted

- Gamora (died pre-purge)
- Hawkeye (unknown)
- Ant-man (unknown)
- Vision (died pre-purge)

But you need to be careful applying that 50% metric too narrowly. Even if everyone we've ever seen in a Marvel movie was wiped out, that could still easily fit into the dead half of all life in the universe. Think about it this way: out of the 5 Guardians left alive at the time of the purge (Rocket, Quill, Drax, Mantis, Groot), only Rocket was spared, which is an 80% kill rate. If you zoom out just a little, 100% of the super heroes could have died and you still wouldn't have any consistency problems with the 50% stat.

Comment: Conversely to the GOG 80% culling: if we exclude Schrödinger's Hawkeye, 100% of the original Avengers team survived. So yeah, subsets can vary wildly.

Comment: Excellent point.

Comment: Do you want to add Loki and Nebula to your list?  Or did you just want to limit it to hero-types?

Comment: I don't consider him a part of the main cast of super heros personally, but even if you did, he wouldn't be counted since he also died pre-purge.

Comment: IIRC Hawkeye is alive, as he is confirmed for Avengers 4

Comment: I am aware about the large numbers law, if you roll 3 tails, the coin's probability is still 50%. But thanks for the heads-up though, will help future readers.

Comment: I'm sure you're right even if Jeremy Renner wasn't in the cast for the next movie. It would be a bad story telling move to kill any of your main cast off screen like that. But, in universe, it's still unknown, so I'm leaving him (and Ant-Man) out.

Comment: An individual coin's probability is 50%, but that's not what is going on. It's not like Thanos flipped a coin for each being in the universe and heads meant live and tails meant die. Yes, that would trend toward 50/50 over a big enough sample, but there's a chance (however improbable) that every flip could come up heads and no one dies, or all tails and everyone dies. What Thanos did is take the total number of beings, and deliberately turned exactly half to tails and killed those. Now, the method for selecting exactly half the coins to turn may have been random, but that's a bit different.

Comment: @Mwr247 - What a curious coincidence.

Comment: You might want to include Nebula

Comment: Yep, small statistical sample counts have caused problems for many a researcher.

Comment: I left off Nebula for the same reason I left off Loki. Obviously they're powered individuals, but I wouldn't put squarely on the "hero" team like the others listed. More allies of convenience for the main heroes. It's up to you if they count or not.

Comment: “out of the 5 Guardians left alive” — of course, there’s no particular reason to think of “these five people who call themselves the Guardians of the Galaxy” as a group. Thanos tells Tony that half of humanity will be spared. Half of one member of the Guardians is human; the rest seem to be a mixture of various species.

Comment: Not counting Okoye and Shuri, ok. But not counting Black Panther?

Comment: I edited my answer to include him. I think I saw Black Widow and just thought I had put him in.

Comment: If that left-field fan theory is correct, this answer is 100% the opposite of the truth...